# how do I perform search/replace in vim while preserving wildcard content?

Tags: vim, replace

Here's what I mean -

Say I have these throughout my file

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from table1").each_hash do ..
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from table2").each_hash do ..
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from table3").each_hash do ..

client.query("select * from table1").each_hash do ..
client.query("select * from table2").each_hash do ..
client.query("select * from table3").each_hash do ..
```

I want to replace **only** the ActiveRecord's `each_hash` calls with `each(:as => :hash)`, so I'd get:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from table1").each(:as => :hash) do ..
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from table2").each(:as => :hash) do ..
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from table3").each(:as => :hash) do ..
```

And leave the client.query rows unaffected.

I know I can use macros, but how do I do this with vim's search/replace? I thought about using this:

```
%s/\.execute(.*).each_hash/ ...something... /g
```

The question is, how do I preserve the actual query through the search and replace (what comes where ...something... is)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perfect use case for the `\zs` atom in vim's regex.  This tells vim to ignore anything before (and including) `\zs` when doing a replacement.

```
:%s/\.execute(.\{-})\.each\zs_hash/(:as => :hash)/
```

A better explaination of `\zs` can be found at `:help /\zs`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `global` command to filter.

```
:g/^ActiveRecord/s/each_hash/each(:as => :hash)/g
```

---

Type `:help :g` to get help:

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
            Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
            lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex to do that:

```
:%s/\(^\(\(.*client.*\)\@!.\)*\)each.hash/\1each(:as => :hash)/g
```

See explanation for `^\(\(.*client.*\)\@!.\)*` part at: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_for_lines_not_containing_pattern_and_other_helpful_searches